# Instance of class Location with fake data

Tags: toit

In order to fake data for my API, I need to be able to instantiate a Location object with values that I choose. The Location object works, when I let the toitbox build the Location object by using GPS. I tried the following:

```
import location show Location

(...)

  fake_lon := Longitude 10.199373
  fake_lat := Latitude 56.143325
  fake_location := Location fake_lat fake_lon
  data.push "track_devices.location" fake_location.to_byte_array
```

Get the following in the terminal: Unresolved identifier: 'Longitude' and Unresolved identifier: 'Latitude'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh... Missed an import. Changed the import to:

```
import location show *
```

Found the problem by changing the settings.json file in vscode by removing :
`"toitLanguageServer.arguments": "",`

Afterwards I reloaded the vscode window and then it showed that the import was that Longitude and Latitude were not imported.